# Calling one method from another within same class in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I was trying to pass a value from one method to another within the class. Because in my code, "if" is calling class's method `on_any_event` that in return should call my another method `dropbox_fn`, which make use of the value from `on_any_event`. Will it work, if the `dropbox_fn` method is outside the class?

```
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        srcpath = event.src_path
        print(srcpath, 'has been ', event.event_type)
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        # print srcpath.split(' ', 12 );
        filename = srcpath[12:]
        return filename  # I tried to call the method. showed error like not callable

    def dropbox_fn(self):  # Or will it work if this methos is outside the class ?
        # this method uses "filename"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    print("entry")
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

The main issue in here is: I cannot call the `on_any_event` method without event parameter. So rather than returning value, calling `dropbox_fn` inside `on_any_event` would be a better way. Can someone help with this?

Comment: For those who've come here from google in search of a canonical dupe: [Python call function within class](//stackoverflow.com/q/5615648)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To call the method, you need to qualify function with `self.`. In addition to that, if you want to pass a filename, add a `filename` parameter (or other name you want).

```
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        srcpath = event.src_path
        print (srcpath, 'has been ',event.event_type)
        print (datetime.datetime.now())
        filename = srcpath[12:]
        self.dropbox_fn(filename) # <----

    def dropbox_fn(self, filename):  # <-----
        print('In dropbox_fn:', filename)
```

Comment: So in the "dropbox_fn", I can use the "filename" directly rather than "self.name=filename"?????

Comment: ok it worked!!. the "dropbox_fn" successfully got the filename from "on_any_event".