# how to call a function in a method from the same package

Tags: python, module, package

I had already read other threads like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825693/calling-one-method-from-another-within-same-class-in-python) an this other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145499/calling-private-function-within-the-same-class-python), but I could not get an answer.
I created a package with the following structure:

```
my_package (folder)
    __init__.py
    my_folder (folder)
        __init__.py
        my_file.py (contains f1 and f2 functions)
    my_other_folder (folder)
        __init__.py
        my_other_file.py (contains of1, of2, of3 functions)
```

at the beginning of my_other_file.py, I had put the import statements:

```
from ..my_file import f1
from ..my_file import f2
```

Inside of1 function, I cannnot call f1 directly, I need to call f1 as my_file.f1 (that's ok).
On the other side, of2 function is a "shell" calling the function of of3 with a function parameter that, depending on the conditions, can be either my_file.f1 or my_file.f2. In other words, the code of function of2 is:

```
def of2:
    if ....:
        result = of3(my_file.f1)
    if ....:
        result = of3(my_file.f2)
    return result
```

the code above is is not working. However, if I use the below (without my_file), everything is ok:

```
def of2:
    if ....:
        result = of3(f1)
    if ....:
        result = of3(f2)
    return result
```

Why I need to call the same function once f1 and another time my_file.f1? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You say your imports look like `from ..function import f1`, but there is no module named `function` in your package.

Comment: thanks, it was my_file, edited

Comment: If you do `import my_file` you have to do `my_file.f1()` to call f1. If you do `from my_file import f1`, the code `f1()` will call `f1()` which is in `my_file`. If you never did `import my_file` I doubt you could do `my_file.f1()` in the `of1` function

Comment: Yes, I agree with the T.Nel,

Comment: Thanks to both. After some tests, I believe my issue was due to the fact that in my real scenario the function had the same name of the file (maybe not a great idea). I changed the import statement to from ..my_folder.my_file import f1, this remove the ambiguity